# Delete a string phrase from a data frame column and replace it python

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace

So, I have two dataframes. the first dataframe is **dataset** conatians several columns, what i will use in this dataframe is the **dataset['text_msg']**, this columns contains text data.

The second Dataframe **sentences_to_exclude** contains the data which type is text type.

The column that i will use in this dataframe is  **sentences_to_exclude['sentences']**.

What i need to do is to verify if there are sentences from **sentences_to_exclude['sentences']** in the first dataframe and remove the whole sentence.
I have tried a function but it didn't work for me: Here is the function i've used ==>

```
  def remove_words(data):
    words_to_remove = sentences_to_exclude['sentences'].lower().split(" ")
    text_body = dataset['text_msg']
    for word in words_to_remove:
        text_body = text_body.replace(word,'' )
    return text_body
```

Here's an exemple of **sentences_to_exclude['sentences']**

> pour un traitement optimal de votre demande, veuillez indiquer les informations ci-dessous

and for the fisrt data frame here's an example of the **dataset['text_msg']**:

> pour un traitement optimal de votre incident, nous vous prions de renseigner les informations ci-dessous : - code transaction : - numero de facture / commande client : - criteres dexecution et message derreur (a attacher en pj) description detaillee de votre demande

Hope that my request is clear
Thank you for help in advance

**Example Data**

```
sentences = ['code transaction', 'Pour un traitement efficace']
text = [ ' i should delete code transaction ', ' i am trying to delete Pour un traitement efficace only from this sentence ' ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Sentences ': sentences })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Text': text})
```

Comment: Please provide example data and an example output also in dataframe format.

Comment: I have edited the post. I have added pictures

Comment: This is not clear at all, I suggest you look at other questions to understand how a good question looks like.

Comment: I have edited my post. i hope that i made it clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still don't understand your question correctly, I will try to help you, but please next time you have to include example data.

To answer your question I will give example dataset and explain how to remove words or sentences from other text:

```
# This is our example data
sentences = ['code transaction', 'Pour un traitement efficace']
text = [ ' i should delete code transaction ', ' i am trying to delete Pour un traitement efficace only from this sentence ' ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Sentences': sentences})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Text': text})

# df1

    Sentences
0   code transaction
1   Pour un traitement efficace

# df2
    Text
0   i should delete code transaction
1   i am trying to delete Pour un traitement effi...
```

Next we want to harmonize our data so we wont have mismatches, so we convert to uppercase:

```
df1['Sentences'] = df1.Sentences.str.upper()
df2['Text'] = df2.Text.str.upper()


    Sentences
0   CODE TRANSACTION
1   POUR UN TRAITEMENT EFFICACE


    Text
0   I SHOULD DELETE CODE TRANSACTION
1   I AM TRYING TO DELETE POUR UN TRAITEMENT EFFI...
```

Now our data is in the right format, we can remove the text from one dataset to another

```
df2['Text_cleaned'] = df2.Text.str.replace('|'.join(df1.Words), '')


    Text                                                Text_cleaned
0   I SHOULD DELETE CODE TRANSACTION                    I SHOULD DELETE
1   I AM TRYING TO DELETE POUR UN TRAITEMENT EFFI...    I AM TRYING TO DELETE ONLY FROM THIS SENTENCE
```

What does `'|'.join(df1.Sentences)` do?
It returns a string delimited by `|`

```
'|'.join(df1.Words)

'CODE TRANSACTION|POUR UN TRAITEMENT EFFICACE'
```

Hope this helps you and answers your question.
You can now apply this logic to your own data.

Comment: Thank u for your response. i have tried what you did but it didn't work i will give an exemple of the data that i am using so it can be much clear for you.